# How to count cycles used by a routine?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'd like to measure the number of cycles a routine uses on a 8051. I'm guessing that I could toggle a pin on and off and measure the period with a scope and multiply it by the number of cycles the 8051 can do in a second. However, I'm not sure if it'd be prone to delays in toggling.

Are there better alternatives? If it's a good idea to use a hardware counter, which timer could be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the I/O pin toggle as you surmised. Toggling an I/O pin in 8051 code takes a known number of cycles and that can be subtracted from what ever scope measurement that you make. If the duration of the routine that you are measuring is many many instructions the additional time consumed toggling the I/O pin may be peanuts in comparison and could be basically ignored. As a matter of fact the measurement on the scope out at several milliseconds would barely register if a few hundred extra nanoseconds were included in the measurement.

In my discussion above I am talking about using an I/O pin that is connected to one of the direct ports of the 8051 part. If your measuring I/O pin is remote from the MCU, such as an I/O on an I<sup>2</sup>C attached port expander, then the interface speed could very well be a factor to consider. Always use a direct port I/O for a scope timing measurement.

If you want to actually see the time overhead of the I/O pin toggling simply put the set and clear of the I/O pin as sequential writes in your code and measure the resulting scope pulse.

Comment: When I make this measurement, I usually have a hard maximum time in mind.  The extra pin-toggle overhead only helps to ensure that the spec is still met after I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding in assembly, use an instruction set reference like [this one](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0509.pdf). It tells you how many clock cycles are used per instruction.

I'm sure there is a reference out there that translates C code to 8051 asm instructions as well so you could tally up the number of cycles by cross referencing.

Comment: You can't use some external reference for that since each compiler will do things differently.  You need to look at the assembly listing output by your own compiler.

Comment: You're right, I should have made that more clear. I was generalizing though, and assuming the guy would understand the concept and look to his own compiler references.